# Is the Dihedral Group of order $24$ isomorphic to the Symmetric Group on $4$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Is the Dihedral Group of order $24$ isomorphic to the Symmetric Group of $4$ elements?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the largest cyclic subgroup possible in both the cases. In the dihedral case we have a cyclic subgroup of order 12. It is not possible in $S_4$.

(Your wording symmetric group *with 4 elements* does not conform to the convention. It should be *on 4 elements*.)

Comment: Nice, I think it's easier to say: $D_{24}$ has an element of order of $12$, while $S_4$ does not.